# How can I safely implement a user python script that edits a root file

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, ubuntu, permissions

My current goal is to edit the /etc/hosts file using a python script so I can block/unblock certain websites with the execution of a .desktop file (the python script comments/uncomments certain lines)

I already have the python script created and it works fine when run as root

However I'm having trouble running the .desktop as a non-root user, while also allowing the python script to edit the root permission /etc/hosts.

I read that its not recommended to add programs into your /usr/share/applications so I tried using ~/.local/share/applications and no surprise, it wont work.

Essentially I'm wondering if there is a way to execute a root python script through a user level .desktop application, while also maintaining secure permissions.

I'm not even sure if this is possible, but I thought I'd ask as it seems like something out of my league as an Ubuntu newbie.

The code for my python is here:

```
with open('hosts.txt', 'r') as file:
# read a list of lines into data
data = file.readlines()
t_change = False
for index, line in enumerate(data):
    clean_line = ' '.join(line.split())
    if t_change and clean_line != "":
        if clean_line == "#end-block":
            t_change = False
        elif line[0] == "#":
            data[index] = line[1:]
        elif line[0] != "#":
            data[index] = "#" + line
    elif clean_line == "#start-block":
        t_change = True
    else:
        data[index] = line
# and write everything back
with open('hosts.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.writelines(data)
```

https://pastebin.com/p8Bat817

And the code for my .desktop application is here:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Name=focus
Icon=/usr/share/applications/icons/focus.svg
Path=/usr/share/applications/
Exec=python3 /home/main/.local/share/applications/focus.py
```

https://pastebin.com/MkpZcmjP

Note: The .desktop is favorited to my taskbar so im able to toggle it quickly (not sure if this would impact any of the permissions)

Comment: There's many ways **safely** could be interpreted here.  I'd argue that having the script sit  under your `$HOME` is inherently insecure; a more sensible place would be under e.g. `/usr/local/bin`. You could add yourself to a file under `/etc/sudoers.d/` that will allow you to execute the script using  `Exec=sudo python3 /home/main/.local/share/applications/focus.py` without a password.